# Plotly horizontal bar - display ALL y axis labels

Tags: plotly

I have a graph that works fine most of the time, unless there are many bars contained in it and then plotly defaultly decides to show only any 2nd y axis label (I can hover on the bars with missing label to view the label but that's not the desired behaviour):

[image]

What can I do to enforce plotly to display all labels? and how do I control gapping between them? height should be dynamic...

Comment: Can you add a reproducible example? and which plotly are you using? JS? Python? R?

Comment: JS , I will try to add example later

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qpkL19ma/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could set `dtick: 1` for your `yaxis`.

From the [documentation](https://plot.ly/javascript/reference/#layout-yaxis-dtick):

> `dtick` (number or categorical coordinate string)
>   Sets the step in-between ticks on this axis.

```js
var data = [{
  "x": [2, 0, 3, 2, 6, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 7, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
  "y": ["department name 1", "department name 2", "department name 3", "department name 4", "department name 5", "department name 6", "department name 7", "department name 8", "department name 9", "department name 10", "department name 11", "department name 12", "department name 13", "department name 14", "department name 15", "department name 16", "department name 17", "department name 18", "department name 19", "department name 20", "department name 21"],
  "name": "Done",
  "orientation": "h",
  "marker": {
    "color": "grey",
    "width": 1
  },
  "type": "bar"
}, {
  "x": [1, 0, 1, 5, 1, 1, 0, 7, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  "y": ["department name 1", "department name 2", "department name 3", "department name 4", "department name 5", "department name 6", "department name 7", "department name 8", "department name 9", "department name 10", "department name 11", "department name 12", "department name 13", "department name 14", "department name 15", "department name 16", "department name 17", "department name 18", "department name 19", "department name 20", "department name 21"],
  "name": "Active",
  "orientation": "h",
  "marker": {
    "color": "green",
    "width": 1
  },
  "type": "bar"
}, {
  "x": [2, 7, 7, 1, 13, 2, 15, 8, 5, 2, 12, 17, 2, 1, 0, 4, 6, 8, 2, 2, 14],
  "y": ["department name 1", "department name 2", "department name 3", "department name 4", "department name 5", "department name 6", "department name 7", "department name 8", "department name 9", "department name 10", "department name 11", "department name 12", "department name 13", "department name 14", "department name 15", "department name 16", "department name 17", "department name 18", "department name 19", "department name 20", "department name 21"],
  "name": "Remaining",
  "orientation": "h",
  "marker": {
    "color": "yellow",
    "width": 1
  },
  "type": "bar"
}]

Plotly.newPlot('plot', data, {
  barmode: "stack",
  title: 'Department stats',
  xaxis: {
    title: 'Sales'
  },
  yaxis: {
    title: 'Departments',
    dtick: 1
  },
  margin: {
    l: 180
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="plot"></div>
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yay! Can you just update to `dtick: 1` instead of `dtick: 0` and I can mark this as the answer